# 1:1:1 Coupling or 1:2 Coupling for OOP?

Tags: oop

For example, is it better to have class A use class B and class B use class C OR to have class A use both class B and class C. I know it might depend on the context, but is there a good guideline for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really have this option. Classes are not written just for fun, they *model* something, usually the business domain.

So the question you should ask yourself is, does/should the concept of `A` know about both `B` and `C`, or does `B` make sense without `C`, etc.?

Usually the domain should sort these things out. If it doesn't, then it by definition doesn't matter.

If the business doesn't matter for this code, i.e. you are writing some technical parts, like Services that just call each other, or something similar, then you are already in "questionable design" territory.